# IDA Assembly change jump destination

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I'm new to reverse engineering and i'm trying to change a

```
__text:001C2BE4                 jz      loc_1C3180
```

which jumps to

```
__text:001C3180 loc_1C3180:
```

into a jump to another subroutine. (`__text:00128DC0 sub_128DC0:`)

However, I don't yet understand how to do this. I can change assembly by editing the hex values but as `loc_*` is just a name given to the subroutine by IDA I don't know how to do this.

Could someone explain how to go about changing the destination of a `jz`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, `loc_1C3180` is *not* `just a name given to the subroutine by IDA` - it is in fact derived directly from the (image-relative) address of the `loc`-ation being jumped to, which in this case is `0x1C3180`.

`jz` is followed by an (in this case) 32-bit signed offset, which is added to the instruction pointer, if the condition is met.

The signed offset to use can be calculated with the following formula (note: may wrap around)

```
JumpOffset = Address of jump target - (Address of Jump instruction + 5)
```

The `+5` comes in because that's the length of the `jz` instruction including the offset.